# Using wx.MDIChildFrame Widgets

Tags: wxpython, widget

I want to put a bunch of widgets into an MDIChildFrame , using wxpython, but i cant find much documentation on how to do so. has anyone created a child frame with alot going on it in so i can take a look at the source code? would be really Helpful

Cheers 
Kemill

Answer (score 0):

The wxPython demo has a fairly complicated window in their MDI with SashWindows demo. However, I keep seeing on the wxPython mailing list that MDI in general isn't usually recommended anyway. If I were you, I'd look at wx.lib.agw.aui. It's a pure python implementation of AUI and fixes a lot of the bugs in wx.aui. I know it's not quite the same, but at least it gets active development.

Comment: The thing is i need the window to pop up when a buttion is clicked (i dont want a pop up window though) the window that pops up has to be a fully functioning GUI within the parent UI. Im not sure if the AUI is what i want.

Comment: Did you look at the wxPython demo for the agw.aui stuff? You should be able to tell from that or ask on the wxPython mailing list for more info or ideas.